# asp.net mvc Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ao utilizar a classe `HttpStatusCodeResult` como retorno para uma `Action`, como faço para redirecionar o usuário para uma página customizada conforme o erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defina no seu arquivo `web.config` as páginas a serem devolvidas para cada código de erro.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
        <error code="404" path="404.html" />
        <error code="500" path="500.html" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

As entradas não precisam ser estáticas. Podem ser, inclusive, retornadas por *Views* de *Controllers* específicos.

O `redirectMode` faz a resposta ser realmente o código desejado. O problema do redirecionamento padrão é que o redirecionamento faz a página de redirecionamento retornar com código 200 (OK), o que é errado.

Comment: E se mesmo eu adicionando o `customErrors` em meu `web.config`, bem conforme você publicou, só trocando o `path` por  `redirect`, e assim mesmo assim não funcionar?

Comment: A resposta do @PauloHDSousa tem alguma coisa sobre configuração de rotas. Não achei necessário colocar parte da resposta dele na minha.

Answer (score 1):

Há vários modos de fazer isso, você pode na própria action identificar o erro e redirecionar, pode também utilizar o global.asx mas eu recomendo você utilizar o web.config para isso.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On">
          <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/400"/>
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Crie a rota, controller e view para a pagina erro que deseja exibir.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "404", 
    "404", 
    new { controller = "Commons", action = "HttpStatus404" }
);
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult HttpStatus404()
{
    return View();
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635114/returning-404-error-asp-net-mvc-3