# Retornando para a página principal ao acessar uma url inválida

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, mvc

Como eu redireciono o usuário para a página principal da aplicação, caso o mesmo tente acessar uma *url* inválida. Por exemplo, `www.teste/teste.html`, no caso a página não existe então sistema direciona o usuário para `www.teste/index.html`, no caso estou usando *asp.net MVC5*.

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Home/Index">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Erro" />
</customErrors>
```

Quando eu acesso uma página não existente ele retorna a mensagem:

> 400 bad request

Alguém poderia me ajudar com essa dúvida?

Comment: Veja se esse caso te ajuda. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47641/asp-net-mvc-bad-request

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso eu passo um parâmetro para minha action que retorna a tela de erro customizada, mas com base no seu código de exemplo creio que o caminho não esteja correto, se sua controller chamar "Erro" e seu método Index for sua tela então basta remover esse til antes da barra. segue abaixo como eu fiz:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Home/_Error/">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Home/_Error/500" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Home/_Error/404" />
    </customErrors>
```